OpenCV's VideoCapture does not capture frames on my Raspberry Pi 5

My pc : Windows
My Pi5 : PiOs
my camera: rev1.3 ov5647

I used vscode SSH to remotely connect Raspberry PI 5 to develop debugging OpenCV program. The program I was thinking of was to achieve the capture of camera video stream. This CV program could correctly recognize that I had a camera, but when I wanted to display one of the frames, I found that Mat variable was empty. Here are some of my messages:
Code:
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open or find the camera!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 25);

    cv::Mat frame;
    while (true) {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) {
            std::cerr << "Could not grab a frame!" << std::endl;
            break; 
        }

        cv::imshow("Video Stream", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}

/* 
The Result of the code is:

Could not grab a frame!
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-0kexp0y1.dep" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-31cvy4ts.g3d"
*/

Other Information:
lytslwy@raspberrypi:~/Project/OpenCV_Pro $ libcamera-hello --list-cameras Available cameras ----------------- 0 : ov5647 [2592x1944 10-bit GBRG] (/base/axi/pcie@120000/rp1/i2c@80000/ov5647@36)     Modes: 'SGBRG10_CSI2P' : 640x480 [58.92 fps - (16, 0)/2560x1920 crop]                              1296x972 [43.25 fps - (0, 0)/2592x1944 crop]                              1920x1080 [30.62 fps - (348, 434)/1928x1080 crop]                              

By the way,I had tried something to test it:   
Like cheese:

(cheese:2840): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 16:18:55.218: gst_value_set_int_range_step: assertion 'end % step == 0' failed

(cheese:2840): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 16:18:55.218: gst_value_set_int_range_step: assertion 'end % step == 0' failed

(cheese:2840): cheese-WARNING **: 16:18:55.466: Description Failed to allocate the requested memory.: ../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2src.c(976): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin28/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:

Buffer pool activation failed

Like GST:

lytslwy@raspberrypi:~/Project/OpenCV_Pro $ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Set pause pipe...

The pipeline is in use and does not require PREROLL ...

Pipes are PREROLLED ...

Set playback pipeline ...

New clock: GstSystemClock

ERR：from /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0：Description Failed to allocate the requested memory。

Additional debugging information：

../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2src.c(976): gst_v4l2src_decide_allocation (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:

Buffer pool activation failed

Error: from component /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0：Internal data stream error.

Additional debugging information：

../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3132): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:

streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)

Execution ended after 0:00:00.095578868

Setting up a NULL pipeline ...

Releasing pipeline resources

 ...

Like guvcview:

V4L2_CORE: (get_v4l2_frame) video stream must be started first

V4L2_CORE: (get_v4l2_frame) video stream must be started first

V4L2_CORE: (get_v4l2_frame) video stream must be started first

But I can use `libcamera-hello --qt-preview` to show what the camera capture in my PC. If you know where I did Wrong,whatever Code,camera... , give me some advises.

context: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79229452

I was in the same boat you were about 4 days ago. I found that using picamera 2 was the only way I could get it to work.
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the YOLO model


# Initialize the Raspberry Pi camera
picam2 = Picamera2()
config = picam2.create_preview_configuration(main={"size": (640, 480)})
picam2.configure(config)
picam2.start()

# Function to process frames with YOLO
def process_frame(frame):

# Display video feed
try:
    print("Press 'q' to quit.")
    while True:
        # Capture frame from the Raspberry Pi camera
        frame = picam2.capture_array()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  # Convert to OpenCV's BGR format

        # Process frame with YOLO
        processed_frame = process_frame(frame)

        # Show the video feed
        cv2.imshow("Video Feed", processed_frame)

        # Exit if 'q' is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
finally:
    picam2.stop()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

The problem I am trying to fix is to display the video feed on the display so that I can see the bounding boxes on the objects YOLO detected. But cv2.imshow does not seem to work for some reason. The other parts of the code work tho.
